# Check if duplicate record within the last 10 seconds

Tags: php, mysqli, duplicates

Is it possible to check if a duplicate record has been inserted within the last 10 or 20 seconds?

As for now I am doing this:

```
INSERT INTO user_pointshistory (ptimestamp, player, points) VALUES (NOW(),'$playerid',$thisPoints)
```

What I want to check on is a record from the same player with the exact same points has been inserted within the last 10 seconds!

Can this be done?

------------- EDIT --------------

I have now tried this but with no luck? Shouldn't I be able to do this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_pointshistory WHERE player='111' AND points=10000 AND ptimestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 SECOND)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo 'GOT A RECORD';
} else {
    echo 'READY FOR AN RECORD';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_pointshistory (ptimestamp, player, points) VALUES (NOW(),'111',10000)";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
```

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Are you storing any kind of timestamp in the row? That would certainly help.

Comment: Ups, was the wrong SQL I had posted. Just edited my post with the right SQL :-/ ptimestamp is DATETIME

Comment: This answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/4056660/

Comment: This `if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){` that won't work, `$row` is undefined. I would replace that with `$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($result); if($numrows > 0){ echo "GOT A RECORD"; }` am pretty sure that will work. @Mansa

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok, so far so good, but now I got "GOT A RECORD" all the time? What am I missing!?

Comment: Try changing `AND ptimestamp < DATE_SUB` to `AND ptimestamp <= DATE_SUB` or `AND ptimestamp == DATE_SUB`. However, you will need to keep reloading till the 10 seconds pass.

Comment: Sorry... Needed to turn the < to an >... Perfect It works :-)

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought. I was going to say that after. Would you like me to put in an answer? and modified to `>`?

Comment: I posted my answer below, since what I posted above did work for you and in order to mark the question as solved. @Mansa

Comment: or, has my answer "not" helped you? I need to know so that I can delete it if it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The following won't work, because `$row` is undefined, where you would be best using [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to check if the row exists.

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

I would replace that with:

```
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
  if($numrows > 0){ 
    echo "GOT A RECORD"; 
}
```

while as you said in comments, turning the `<` in `ptimestamp < DATE_SUB` to an `>`

Answer (score 0):

I strongly second rjdown's response in that you should create a timestamp, so you can first check the database with the timestamp stored and a new timestamp generated before submitting the new row.

Comment: Sorry, was the wrong SQL I had posted... ptimestamp is a DATETIME field

Comment: Okay, so now before inserting an entry you would do a SELECT query on the player you are about to INSERT and if $newdate - $row['ptimestamp'] >= 10 { INSERT } ELSE { echo ERROR }

Comment: Ok, just thought that this maybe could be done in one sentence, but I will try this (y)

Comment: I tried it a little different than what you said... Still no luck though? Why can't this be done?!?! Look in the initiated post.